# Finding the closest point between a plane formed by a equation and another point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

There's a question about the geometry on  the $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $ topic of my book that goes as follows:

- Consider the plane $\pi$ : $ 2x + 3y - z = 20 $ and the point $P $(-4 ,2 ,6).

Find the point $Q$ under the $\pi$ plane that is closest to $P$ and find also the distance between $P$ and $Q$.

Now, first of all. How should I interpret a equation forming a plane? In that sense what does it mean to make the same equation equals to a number (20 in this example)? Like, if i can assign lots of values into $ x , y$ and $z$, wouldn't it form a bunch of planes instead of one plane? Second, how should i proceed in order to actually solve this type of exercises, at least the first steps or some intuition. Is the distance between the points $Q$ and $P$ related to the norm of a vector? Any tool i could use to better visualize how this would look in 3d? Thanks!

Comment: The number, $20$ in your question for example, limits the possible solutions to the equation and therefore creates a shape in the euclidean space.

Comment: If you have also studied lines in space, you could find Q by finding the line through P which is perpendicular to the plane, and then finding where the line and plane intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation for the plane
$$\pi : 2x + 3y - z = 20$$
defines one and only one plane in $\mathbb R^3$. As you know, a plane is a 2-dimensional linear surface. You can think of this in the following way: You can pick any values for $x$ and $y$ as you like, but then $z$ has to be the specific value:
$$ z = 2x + 3y - 20$$
and in the same way, you could pick any value for $x$ and $z$, or $y$ and $z$, but then the last variable would have to be a specific value.

To the question itself. So, you want to find a point $Q = (q_1, q_2, q_3)$ on the plane $\pi$, i.e. you have $2q_1 + 3q_2 - q_3 = 20$ such that $Q$ is as close to $P$ as possible. As you mentioned, this is the same as minimizing the norm $\| Q - P\|$.

This can be done by projecting $P$ onto $\pi$.

You can visualize this by drawing it. Drawing a plane properly can be a bit tricky, but if you find a couple of points on the plane you can generally get a decent picture from there.

Comment: Perfect Calle, thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome!